# is there a cleaner way of achieving this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

im attempting to only display certain records from a table based on different information passed through, and if none of the requirements are met it redirects to home. the code is all functioning, just wanted to see how other would have tackled this

```
if current_user.admin?
  @schedules = Schedule.all
elsif current_user.team_id?
  @schedules = Schedule.find_all_by_team_id(current_user[:team_id])
else
  redirect_to root_path, :status => 301, :alert => "Please contact your club administrator to be assigned to a team."
  return
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always move complex logic away from your controllers.

```
class Schedule
  def self.for(user)
    case user.role #you should define the role method in User
      when User::ADMIN
        scoped
      when User::TEAM
        where(team_id: user[:team_id])
    end
  end
end
```

in your controller:

```
@schedules = Schedule.for(current_user)

redirect_to root_path, :status => 301, :alert => "Please contact your club administrator to be assigned to a team." unless @schedules
```

Comment: How is adding a role any better than using the `admin?` method? Seems to achieve the same result with more code.

Comment: You may want to use a case statement if you have more than two roles in the future.

Answer (score 0):

An approach to your problem.

```
@schedules = Schedule.all if current_user.admin?
@schedules = Schedule.find_all_by_team_id(current_user[:team_id]) if current_user.team_id?
if @schedules.nil?
  redirect_to root_path, :status => 301, :alert => "Please contact your club administrator 
    to be assigned to a team."
else
  #Your normal redirect
end
```